# Doubly Linked list Insertion

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, pass-by-reference, doubly-linked-list

I made a program to insert a element in doubly linked list given below(ignore create and display functions
Which was working perfectly right till it found the index to be inserted is 5 ,where it fails .Although i made another program to encounter this and now it isn't displaying anything. I used chat gpt  but just got wrong answers .Pls help me and also any guidance for when i think a program and its algo it works perfectly but when i actually compile it .It doesn't work, even if i have traced my program like 10 times
Another program:

````
     #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct Node {
  struct Node *prev;
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
}new;
new *insert (new *head,int index,int num);
void display(new *head);
void create(new *head,int A[],int n);
void create(new *head,int A[],int n)
{
  head->data=A[0];
  head->next=head->prev=NULL;
  new *last=head;
  for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
  {
      new *t=(new *)malloc(sizeof(new));
      t->data=A[i];
      t->prev=last;
      t->next=NULL;
      last->next=t;
      last=t;
  }
}
void display(new *head)
{
  new * temp=NULL;
  int flag=0;
  printf("Next:");
  while(head)
  {
      printf("%d ",head->data);
      if(!head->next||flag==0){
          temp=head;
          flag=1;
      }
      head=head->next;
  }
  printf("\nPREV:");
  while(temp)
  {
      printf("%d ",temp->data);
      temp=temp->prev;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
new *insert (new *head,int index,int num)
{
  new*q=NULL,*temp=NULL;
  int flag=0;
  if(index==0)
  {
      return insert(head,0,9);
  }
  int i=0;
  while(i!=index)
  {
      if(!q->next&&flag==1)temp=q; 
      flag=1;
      q=head;
      head=head->next;
      i++;
  }
  new*t=(new*)malloc(sizeof(new));
  t->next=head;
  int y=0;
  t->data=num;
  if(!(head&&q))
  {
      temp->next=t;
      t->prev=temp;
      y=1;
  }
  if(y==0)
  {
  q->next=t;
  t->prev=q;
  head->prev=t;
  }
}
int main()
{
  new * head=(new *)malloc(sizeof(new));
  int A[5]={1,2,3,6,7};
  create(head,A,5);
  display(head);
  int i=3;
  insert(head,i,87);
  display(head);
}
  ```
````

Comment: If you want help to debug your program, please provide a [mre] (one, not two) so that we can actually compile your code.

Comment: Sir, example as ,in  a set of numbers with a index to be inserted ?if yes then i may add the create function and the display function as well ,and the array of numbers being the one in the code

Comment: Yes, please add the missing functions and the expected output. Please also remove one of the snippets and concentrate on finding the bug in one of them.

Comment: Ok Sir ,i will add the required data in a minute

Comment: Sir ,I have edited my answer and now it contains my full program, but please ignore the insert0() function it has no use

Comment: Which one of the programs do you need help with? I will help with one of them so please remove the other. _"please ignore the insert0() function it has no use"_ - That's not how this works. You should _remove_ everything that has no relevance to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I have removed the working program, the one now is the irritating one

Comment: Ok, but you still call `insert` (which doesn't return a `new*` in all paths) - so therefore the program has undefined behavior. You also forgot to mention what the expected output of this program is.

Comment: Even if it doesn't return a new* in all paths ,i don't change it's initial pointer head to the insert function's returned value ,i am just giving the insert functions return value to the initial head when i encounter the index to 0 so that i can move the head pointer to the respective new node

Comment: You haven't understood how C works. If you declare a function to return a `new*`, it _must_ return a `new*`. It's not optional. The only version of optional is if you return a `NULL` pointer. If you don't return anything, the whole program has undefined behavior and nothing the program does can be trusted. It can crash - or worse, produce erroneous output. Any output is valid when the program has UB. Anyway, if you want me to ignore `insert`, then remove `insert`.

Comment: ... and still I don't know what you expect the program to output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters the typedef name `new` is not good. It will be much better for example to use typedef name `Node`

```
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node
{
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
    int data;
};
```

you should decide what to do if the specified index is greater than the current number of nodes in the list: whether to append a new node or to report an error.

As for your code then it can not run fine.

For example if the specified index is equal to 0 then this code snippet

```
if(index==0)
{
    return insert(head,0,9);
}
```

invokes an infinite recursive call of the function itself. Also it is unclear why the third argument is the integer constant 9.

Also the function returns nothing if the specified index is not equal to 0.

And this statement in main

```
new * head=(new *)malloc(sizeof(new));
```

does not make sense. For example if the user will not call the function `create` then calls of the function `insert` will invoke undefined behavior.

Initially a list should be empty. That is in main you should write

```
new *head = NULL;
```

I would declare and define the function `insert` the following way.

```
int insert( Node **head, size_t index, int data )
{
    int success = 0;

    if (index == 0)
    {
        Node *node = ( Node * )malloc( sizeof( *node ) );
        success = node != NULL;

        if (success)
        {
            node->data = data;
            node->prev = NULL;
            node->next = *head;

            if (*head != NULL) ( *head )->prev = node;

            *head = node;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Node *current = *head;

        while ( current != NULL && --index != 0 )
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        success = index == 0;

        if (success)
        {
            Node *node = ( Node * )malloc( sizeof( *node ) );
            success = node != NULL;

            if (success)
            {
                node->data = data;
                node->prev = current;
                node->next = current->next;
                current->next = node;

                if (node->next != NULL) node->next->prev = node;
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

The function returns `1` if a node in the given position was inserted in the list or `0` if the specified index is out of the acceptable range `[0, number of existent nodes]` or a memory for a new  node was not allocated.

Instead of the return type `int` you could introduce an enumeration that will classify possible errors or success.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;
    int data;
} Node;

int insert( Node **head, size_t index, int data )
{
    int success = 0;

    if (index == 0)
    {
        Node *node = ( Node * )malloc( sizeof( *node ) );
        success = node != NULL;

        if (success)
        {
            node->data = data;
            node->prev = NULL;
            node->next = *head;

            if (*head != NULL) ( *head )->prev = node;

            *head = node;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Node *current = *head;

        while ( current != NULL && --index != 0 )
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        success = index == 0;

        if (success)
        {
            Node *node = ( Node * )malloc( sizeof( *node ) );
            success = node != NULL;

            if (success)
            {
                node->data = data;
                node->prev = current;
                node->next = current->next;
                current->next = node;

                if (node->next != NULL) node->next->prev = node;
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}

FILE *display( const Node *head, FILE *fp )
{
    for (; head != NULL; head = head->next)
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", head->data );
    }

    fputs( "null", fp );

    return fp;
}

void clear( Node **head )
{
    while (*head)
    {
        Node *tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    Node *head = NULL;

    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 7 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    int success = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; success && i < N; i++)
    {
        success = insert( &head, i, a[i] );
    }

    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );

    clear( &head );

    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 7 -> null
null
```

Try to write the function `create` yourself. It should be declared like

```
size_t create( Node **head, const int a[], size_t n );
```

The function returns the actual number of added elements of an array to the list.

Pay attention to that it would be reasonsable to introduce one more structure like for example

```
struct DoubleLinkedList
{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
    size_t size;
};
```

And define functions that will deal with an object of this structure type.

Comment: @Harshal Malani I am sorry. The initial provided by me function insert was incorrect. I have updated it now.